# react-native android duplicate declaration

Tags: react-native

## code below is mine.

## and I am using atom, genie motion.

it saids Duplicate declaration "MyScene" at ~ \index.android.js:20:7

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MyScene extends Component {
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      title: 'MyScene'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hi! My name is {this.props.title}.</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

//import MyScene from './MyScene';

class YoDawgApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyScene />
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YoDawgApp', () => YoDawgApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the packager is still looking at your commented out import statement. That seems wrong to me but a quick fix is either:

1. Remove the commented out code
2. Change "MyScene" in that commented out code to literally anything else (other then "YoDawgApp")